# scrreprt: parskip = full in text but not in footnotes

Tags: footnotes, koma-script, parskip

I write a document with the `scrreprt` class in which I use the option `parskip = full`. This automatically applies to footnotes, too.

How can I set several footnotes on one page without a parskip between them?

Comment: Without a MWE (minimal working example) we can not reproduce the issue because it is not the default behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default there is no parskip between footnotes even if option `parskip=full` is set for the document:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\footnote{Footnote One: \blindtext\par\blindtext}

\blindtext\footnote{Footnote Two: \blindtext}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

So without additional informations and a MWE the described issue can not be reproduced.

Comment: Very stupid mistake from my side: I used `\kant[1]` for generating the testfootnote, which always ends with a new paragraph, which then was correctly set in the footnote. Anyway, thanks for your effort!